# Bypass cache check for logged in users in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using cache_action in my controllers, and I would like to bypass checking the cache for logged in users on some pages. My login system is Devise/Omniauth.

I thought I would find something in the caching system that I could integrate into a before_filter, but no dice.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this, but I've never tried it myself:

```
caches_action :index, :unless => lambda { user_signed_in? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 4, you can use the CacheHelper's [cache_unless](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper.html#method-i-cache_unless) and Devise's `user_signed_in?`

```
<%= cache_unless user_signed_in?, project do %>
  <b>All the topics on this project</b>
  <%= render project.topics %>
<% end %>
```